# Bug when clicking on Edit email settings from an email

Tags: bug, email

I clicked on 'Edit email settings' from my gmail account.  I was directd to the [Page Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/404) page because I wasn't logged in.  After I clicked on the [Log In](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add?ssrc=login) link and logged in, I was taken to a page that said Invalid Request.

I expect the link from my email to take me to the login page if I'm not logged in.  Once I've logged in, it should redirect me to the Edit Email Settings page.